# Form submit onchange & back to the same line

Tags: php, html, forms

After the onsubmit event, can the form go back to the same position last filled out?
I have a form that's 200+ lines long. Mostly checkboxes/radio buttons for a machine startup checklist.
When someone clicks a button, the page submits and reloads but then the user has to scroll all the way down to where they left off.
Can I get it to go back to the last line they checked?

```
<form id="formName" action="" method="POST">
  <label for="check1">Check 1:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="0" onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()"><br>
  <label for="check2">Check 2:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="0" onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()"><br>
  <br>
  ... 200+ lines ...<br>
  <br>
  <label for="check214">Check 214:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check214" name="check214" value="0" onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, of course. How do you define "last filled out"? Adding an ID to the form action should already work, like `form.php#check214`

Comment: Why would I need to specify the last line? I was thinking of adding something to the onchange parameters referencing the check number so that I can add the url to the form action parameter like you mentioned. [ action="form.php#$value???" ]

Comment: If you want to, do that. But the user experience is pretty bad if you submit the form after each change

Comment: We submit after each check to update the SQL. Some checklists can be 2000+ lines for a big piece of equipment and take 3 guys a full day to work on, each will take a chuck of the list on a tablet. It would suck getting a couple hours of checks done and accidently reload the checklist. It's also so the people up in the ivory tower can see the progress.

Comment: I agree with @NicoHaase that it might not be best for submit after each checked input. But anyhow thats your decision. You could do this in the `onchange="document.getElementById('formName').action = 'form.php#check' + (parseInt(this.id.replace(/\D/g, '')) + 1); document.getElementById('formName').submit();"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @slashroot, works great!